# php plugin question

Tags: php

I have a PHP-mysql application which is running by portable server (i.e.XAMPP). The client buy additional functions (like Chart, report) after using the gerneral app.

However, for example, there are some links need to be linked from general app to additional function after installing. Those links will be disabled when the addtional function hasn't been installed.

My question is how to solve the above scenario? Really appreciate for any help and Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you're trying to enable links once the customer buys additions to your product?

Comment: We need more information. Is your application storing these additional functions in separate files? If so are these files always included in the program but hidden from the user? Or are they stored in a database? or are they methods of classes that you're just not giving the user access to?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to define a constant, for example `PLUGIN_CHART`, in the plugin and in the main app just check if the constant exists and is true.

If the plugins are actual functions, another way is to use [`function_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) to check if it's available.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of going about it, here is a simple way:

Have a directory called plugins. Within that directory create a folder for each plugin you have. For each of your client, put only the plugins they will be using.

Now, instead of linking each possible plugin, check to see if the plugin is loaded (or at least if the directory exists), if it does, create a link!